Issue declaring reactfx as a dependency
I am working on adding comments to a codeArea from richtextfx using reactfx to detect some stuff, but while declaring it in my module info and build.gradle i only get errors
I tried to add requires reactfx; to my module-info, anything else will give me an error on the spot, but using that will give me an error while compiling (error: module not found: reactfx
requires reactfx;). I added the dependency with implementation: 'org.reactfx:reactfx:2.0-M5' to my build.gradle and it still gave me the error. Finally i tried the manual install but again it gave me the exact same error. This is my module info:
  ´module com.raven.microforge {

        requires javafx.controls;

        requires org.slf4j;

        requires org.fxmisc.richtext;

        requires com.google.gson;

        requires com.dlsc.preferencesfx;

        requires reactfx;

        exports com.raven.microforge;
    }´

and the dependencies part of my build.gradle:
´
dependencies {
    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logbackVersion"

    implementation "ch.qos.logback:logback-core:$logbackVersion"

    implementation "org.fxmisc.richtext:richtextfx:0.11.2"

    implementation "com.dlsc.preferencesfx:preferencesfx-core:11.17.0"

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'

    implementation 'org.reactfx:reactfx:2.0-M5'
}

´
This might be a dumb question but I seriously cant see what I did wrong.
